# How to correctly use \IfEndWith (or any alternative) in \title{} \chapter{} etc.?

Tags: macros, conditionals

As a latex noob I am stumped by how to correctly use `\IfEndWith` in `\title{}` `\chapter{}` etc. This is my code:

```
\newcommand{\hero}{John}
\newcommand{\heroap}{\IfEndWith{\hero}{s}{\hero'}{\hero's}}
```

These commands are set in the preamble and I can use `\heroap` anywhere in my document without any problems, except when I try to use it in `\title{}` or `\chapter{}` (and presumably similar built-in constructs).

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am also happy to receive suggestions for alternatives to `\IfEndWith`, it just seemed to fit my use case spot on.

Comment: Please extend your example to a full minimal self contained example. Then we can also see where `\IfEndWith` comes from (which you do not specify). I'd guess that `\IfEndWith` does not expand macros.

Comment: I guess it would be much simpler to write out the names.Maybe using placeholders and copy/paste.

Comment: @daleif Thank you for your input! I was just about to post the full minimal self-contained example, when I noticed that my question was already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the command `\heroap` in a 'safe' way, i.e., use `\NewDocumentCommand`. Otherwise, when using the 'old-fashioned' way, you have to prefix `\heroap` in unsafe environments by `\protect`.

**Contemporary method:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\hero}{John}
\NewDocumentCommand\heroap{}{\IfEndWith{\hero}{s}{\hero'}{\hero's}}
\begin{document}
\title{\heroap}
\author{\heroap}
\maketitle
\section{\heroap}
\end{document}
```

**Old-fashioned way:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\hero}{John}
\newcommand\heroap{\IfEndWith{\hero}{s}{\hero'}{\hero's}}
\begin{document}
\title{\heroap}
\author{\heroap}
\maketitle
\section{\protect\heroap}
\end{document}
```

Both methods will result in the same output:

[image]

Comment: +1, but with the `\protect` of the section is enough in this case.

Comment: @Fran Yes, you are right, thanks. I had a typing error when testing it, and attributed it to the missing `\protect` in `\title`, and later forgot to remove it.

Comment: @gernot Thank you for your answer! Much appreciated. It solves my problem. A follow-up question: I am still having trouble with the space following the output from `\heroap`. E.g. `\chapter{\heroap\space Adventure}` produces a correct space in the chapter heading, but the space is missing in the TOC. I used your suggestion with `\NewDocumentCommand`. Any ideas?

Comment: @dholter make a habit of writing this type of macros like this `\heroap{}` then it will not eat the space.

Comment: @daleif Thank you! It does not, indeed.